# Why give in firefox I get error:'no such table: django_session' on /server/admin/, in chrome it works

Tags: django, google-chrome, firefox

I start with Django 2.0.2 course. I discovered that in chrome I get on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ the Django Home page, in Firefox Dev. as well. On opening http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin in chrome it works as expected http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/. However in firefox I get 'no such table: Django_session'.

I work in Windows 10, virtualenv created by pipenv.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run python manage.py migrate command to create django_sessions table in your database.